# How to get Dell iDrac FirmWare version from VmWare Esxi 4.x\5.x via SNMP?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp, drac, dell-openmanage

How can I get Dell iDrac Firmware version on Esxi 4.x\5.x via SNMP.
I tried to check via snmpwalk -c public -v 2c esxihost 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.1.1.8 but got "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" all the time.
I see just  1.3.6.1.4.1.6876 MIB (VMWare) but this have no needed information for me. 
I, also, have no success after installing OpenManage packages and do not see any changes. Althought, here http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19442142 I found out that the  Server Administrator does not support SNMP Get and Set operations on VMWare ESXi 4.X and ESXi 5.x as the required SNMP support is unavailable. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have more luck polling the drac controller than the esxi host.

Dell has even a [technical white paper for Nagios agent less monitoring](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20438638/download)

If you really need to get the info from the esxi hosts, then your best bet will be using the vmware sdk using the wsman interface.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now if I ping mgr-card directly I get 674(Dell) Mib Tree. I'll try finding needed oids.